# Web Scraping, data mining, data extraction

Tags: html, parsing, screen-scraping, data-mining

I am tasked with creating a web scraping software, and I don't know where to even begin. Any help would be appreciated, even just telling me how this data is organized, or what "type" of data layout the website is using would help, because I would be able to Google search that term.

http://utilsub.lbs.ubc.ca/ion/default.aspx?dgm=x-pml:/diagrams/ud/Default/7330_FAC-delta_V2.4.1/7330_FAC-delta_V2.4.1-pq.dgm&node=Buildings.Angus_addition&logServerName=QUERYSERVER.UTIL2SUB&logServerHandle=327952

http://utilsub.lbs.ubc.ca/ion/default.aspx?dgm=x-pml:/diagrams/ud/network.dgm&node=Buildings.AERL&unique_id=75660a13-5145-42d5-b661-a50f328306c7&logServerName=QUERYSERVER.UTIL2SUB&logServerHandle=327952

Basically, I need to extract the "harmonic values" from this website. Specifically, I need the 9 numbers displayed on the second link. The numbers are not passed to HTML, they just seem to update automatically every few seconds. I need to able to extract these values in real time as they update. Even if that is not possible I still need to show that doing such web scraping is impossible. I am not given any API's to any of the back end, and do not know how they're site receives the data.

Overall, ANY help would be appreciated, even if its just some simple search terms to put me in the right direction. I am currently clueless in terms of web scraping/data mining/

Comment: "The numbers are not passed to HTML.." -- sorry, but provable not true. "View source" shows the actual numbers, even on my iPad. You 'only' have to locate them, there is a *lot* of fluff around them. If you want to scrape them "in real-time", you can post frequent requests using `curl` or another wget utility to load the html, then seek for the encomapssing code to extract the numbers.

Comment: I recommend a web search for "web scraping" and the name of the programming language that you'd like to / feel most comfortable working in, and taking a stab at it from there.  If *then* you can't figure it out, posting SPECIFIC questions here will likely get a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Web Scraping**

To parse HTML from a website is otherwise called Screen Scraping. It’s a process to access external website information (the information must be public – public data) and processing it as required. For instance, if we want to get the average ratings of Nokia Lumia 1020 from different websites we can scrap the ratings from all the websites and calculate the average in our code. So we can say, as a general “User” what you can have as “Public Data”, you’ll be able to scrap that using HTML Agility Pack easily.

*Try These :*

**ASP.NET** : [**HTMLAgilityPack**](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (open source library)

[Scraping HTML DOM elements using HtmlAgilityPack (HAP) in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659019/Scraping-HTML-DOM-elements-using-HtmlAgilityPack-H)

**PHP & CURL** : [WEB SCRAPING WITH PHP & CURL](http://www.jacobward.co.uk/web-scraping-with-php-curl-part-1/)

**Node.js** : [Screen Scraping with Node.js](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/web-scraping-with-node-js/)

**YQL & Ajax** : [Screen scraping using YQL and AJAX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660151/Screen-scraping-using-YQL-and-AJAX)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have tried to use the YQL console, however it does not seem to take the actual real time data that I need. Another question is which of these approaches can actually take this data in real time?

Comment: This might be your solution: http://www.lightstreamer.com/ , but I'm not sure about it. As i haven't tired. But they say that they can scrap data on real time and seeing their demo it seems that they really do.

Comment: Thanks, I have downloaded their software, and looking at it right now, it looks promising. I'll keep updating. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/
It is very easy to use, you have to override one classe which is Controller.java.

You only need to specify the seeds and it returns the text and the HTML data in two variables for every website crawled.

Answer (score 0):

The second link is pulling information from an API every few seconds. Using Google Chrome you can inspect things like this using the developer tools and clicking on "Network" then. You then see which requests are sent and can easily replicate them by right clicking the request -> copy as CURL. You then get something like this, which includes all headers and post data sent by the request in an CURL command. This is what the second link was calling:

```
curl 'http://utilsub.lbs.ubc.ca/ion/default.aspx/GetRTxmlData' -H 'Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=oq0qiwuqbb3g3453jvyysvjx' -H 'Origin: http://utilsub.lbs.ubc.ca' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Host: utilsub.lbs.ubc.ca' -H 'Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Referer: http://utilsub.lbs.ubc.ca/ion/default.aspx?dgm=x-pml:/diagrams/ud/network.dgm&node=Buildings.AERL&unique_id=75660a13-5145-42d5-b661-a50f328306c7&logServerName=QUERYSERVER.UTIL2SUB&logServerHandle=327952' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary $'{\'dgm\':\'x-pml:/diagrams/ud/network.dgm\',\'id\':\'75660a13-5145-42d5-b661-a50f328306c7\',\'node\':\'\'}' --compressed
```

The API returns XML wrapped in JSON.

You might wanna use CURL with PHP as codeSpy said, you just have to set all the headers and post data and replicate the request properly, otherwise the API wont respond to your request.